# Message name conflict in symbols' database. What happens if I do not register a message with the symbols' database?

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I'm working on a software that calls multiple gRPC services from various external sources. Conflicts in message names may arise, as these services might not have a package name and they might use messages with the same names. I can't really change the .proto files as I'm not the developer of those services.

As far as I understand, in Python's gRPC implementation, for each message a function call is made to `_sym_db.RegisterMessage(<message>)` and the message's `DESCRIPTOR` is extracted and used as the key to add that message to the symbols' database. So, completely unrelated messages from different files may conflict as gRPC tries to add them to the symbols' database with the same key.

On the other hand, I tried commenting out all references to `_sym_db.RegisterMessage(<message>)` in the auto-generated gRPC code and everything still works fine. By my understanding, this database is used to reference the compiled code by symbol after it's imported for the first time, but client calls can still be made even if this database is not used at all.

Can anybody confirm if this is true or false?
Also, do you think it would make sense to raise a PR where a different key than the message's `DESCRIPTOR` is used in the symbols' database? Like file + descriptor or something.

Thanks!